# Mobile menu background

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu that appears like this below, I don't want the gray background to appear behind the hamburger button, rather want it to appear below, I dont want it to show at all once its not clicked. I dont know where to edit it in my code though, I have tried everything.

Background of my menu button

[image]

When menu is clicked

[image]

### HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="hamburger-menu-wrapper">
<button class="hamburger-menu">
<span>toggle menu</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="menu-list">
<div class="menu-list">
<a href="#About">About us</a><br>
<a href="#Services">Services</a><br>
<a href="#Clients">Clients</a><br>
<a href="#Contact">Contact us</a><br>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body 
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow-x: hidden; 
}

.hamburger-menu-wrapper 
{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #323232;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 999 !important;
  position: static;
 }

.hamburger-menu-wrapper.bounce-effect 
{ 
  animation: bounce 0.3s ease 1; 
 }

.hamburger-menu  
 {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
 }

.hamburger-menu:focus 
{ 
  outline: none; 
 }

.hamburger-menu span 
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #02D5FD;
}

.hamburger-menu span:before, .hamburger-menu span:after 
{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #02D5FD;
  content: "";
}

.hamburger-menu span:before 
{ 
 top: -7px; 
}

.hamburger-menu span:after 
{  
 bottom: -7px; 
}

.hamburger-menu span:before, .hamburger-menu span:after 
{
 transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.hamburger-menu span:before 
{ 
  transition-property: top, transform;
  }

.hamburger-menu span::after 
 { 
    transition-property: bottom, transform; 
    }

.hamburger-menu.active span  
 { 
  background: none; 
}

.hamburger-menu.active span:before
 {
 top: 0;
 transform: rotate(225deg);
 }

.hamburger-menu.active span:after 
{
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
 }

.hamburger-menu.active span:before, .hamburger-menu.active span:after 
{ 
transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce
{ 
  0% {transform: rotate(0);}
  45% {transform: rotate(15deg);}
  90% {transform: rotate(-7deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(0);}
 }

.menu 
{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #818184;
 opacity: 0.9;
 }

.menu-list 
 {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.menu-list a
 {
 color: #C6D2D6;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px 0;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 z-index:999 ;
}

.menu-list a:hover
 { 
 color: #02D5FD; 
 }

 .menu-overlay 
 {
  transition: margin 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 999 !important;
  }
```

### JQuery

```
(function()
{
      'use strict';
      $('.hamburger-menu').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('.menu-overlay').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
      $('.menu .menu-list').slideToggle( 'slow', 'swing' );
      $('.hamburger-menu-wrapper').toggleClass('bounce-effect');
      } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.menu-overlay').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
      $('.menu .menu-list').slideToggle( 'slow', 'swing' );
      $('.hamburger-menu-wrapper').toggleClass('bounce-effect');
      }
      })
      })();
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong, everything else is working just perfect, it's mobile responsive and the button is working perfectly. I just need help with the grey background if anyone can help me please. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question, do want to remove the grey background, mak it non-transparent or something else?

Comment: `want it to appear below` *it*: the button or the grey background? (& more instances of unclear references)

Answer (score 1):

Am not clear about your Question.Upto my knowledge i think this is what you are expecting..
You can use add remove class for hiding showing background color.
http://jsfiddle.net/w9ew0nrw/11/

add css in your code

```
.showback {
   background-color: #818184;
   transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

and add js

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';
     $('.hamburger-menu').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
              $(".menu").removeClass('showback');
              $(this).removeClass('active');
              $('.menu-overlay').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
              $('.menu .menu-list').slideToggle( 'slow', 'swing' );
              $('.hamburger-menu-wrapper').toggleClass('bounce-effect');
          } else {
              $(this).addClass('active');
              $(".menu").addClass('showback');
              $('.menu-overlay').fadeToggle( 'fast', 'linear' );
              $('.menu .menu-list').slideToggle( 'slow', 'swing' );
              $('.hamburger-menu-wrapper').toggleClass('bounce-effect');
         }
      });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks soooooo much radha for your help, sorry if the question was slightly vague, I tried to explain it as best as possible, but your answer was exactly what I was after. Much appreciated :)

Comment: thats great...kindly make a tick mark if my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

i dont really understand the question your asking, this is what i came up with...

i see there is an rgba() code in your css which decides the overlay color, change the last number to 1  to remove the opacity.

```css
 .menu-overlay 
 {
  transition: margin 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 999 !important;
  }
```

i hope this helps, let me know.

-MultiDutch